# How to escape bash code so that it can be run by `system()`?

Tags: r, bash

```
R> system('bash -c "cat <(seq 3)"', intern=T)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

If I use any bash-specific features, I will have to manually call `bash -c`. But that means I will have to properly escape it so that it can be embedded in a string. For example, I can manually escape the bash code like this.

```
R> system('bash -c "cat <(printf \'%s\\n\' {a..c})"', intern=T)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

But how to automate the escape process robustly, so that it will work on arbitrary bash code.

Essentially, I want to have a function that can turn any legal bash command string (e.g., `cat <(printf '%s\n' "'" {a..c})`) into a string runable by `system()`. Note the requirement of robustness, it must work with any arbitrary legal bash command.

EDIT: It seems that if `printf %q` from bash can be implemented in R, this problem may be solved? If so, how to implement it?

Comment: You don't. You put that code in a bash script, and call that script from R

Comment: Since R 4.0.0, you can use raw strings: `system(r"[bash -c "cat <(printf '%s\n' {a..c})"]", intern =  TRUE)`. See `?Quotes`.

Comment: No. This is not sufficient. For example, it can not work for `system(r"[bash -c "cat <(printf '%s\n' "'" {a..c})"]")`. Once you start escaping '"', the code becomes ugly.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid manually inserting escapes in `system` commands, you can construct the commands using `shQuote`, possibly recursively. `shQuote` wraps its argument (a string) in single or double quotes depending on its content, inserting escapes as necessary, and returns the result. `sprintf` and `paste` are often useful here:

```r
cmd_bash <- sprintf("cat <(printf %s %s %s)", shQuote("%s\n"), shQuote("'"), "{a..c}")
cmd_bash
## [1] "cat <(printf '%s\n' \"'\" {a..c})"

cmd <- paste("bash -c", shQuote(cmd_bash))
cmd
## [1] "bash -c \"cat <(printf '%s\n' \\\"'\\\" {a..c})\""

system(cmd, intern = TRUE)
## [1] "'" "a" "b" "c"
```

FWIW, you can read from `stdin` interactively with `readLines`, using <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to signal EOF and/or argument `n` to signal EOF after `n` lines have been entered:

```r
zzz <- readLines(stdin())
## '
## a
## b
## c
## ^D

zzz
## [1] "'" "a" "b" "c"

zzz <- readLines(stdin(), n = 4L)
## '
## a
## b
## c

zzz
## [1] "'" "a" "b" "c"

zzz <- system(paste("bash -c", shQuote(readLines(stdin(), n = 1L))), intern = TRUE)
## cat <(printf '%s\n' "'" {a..c})

zzz
## [1] "'" "a" "b" "c"
```

In the last example, the Bash command was typed as if at a Bash prompt, in the running R process.

Comment: This recursive nesting will not be readable when the bash code is complex. Is there anything in R like heredoc (with `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF`) in bash that I can read in a string verbatim without any escaping?

Comment: I've updated my answer - not sure if it helps...

Comment: Heredoc of `<<'EOF'` in bash is essentially embedding an external file in a bash script verbatim. It is sad that R doesn't have a feature that mimic this. Using an external file to hold the bash script is fine, but it is not as convenient. And if a file can be used, why not just put it a bash script then just run that bash script, so that there will be no `bash -c ...` issue.

Comment: R has multiline strings for the purpose of embedding scripts in other languages, but they don't meet your "verbatim" requirement. In your situation, I _would_ just write a Bash script and use `system` to run it...